# Why does this give me an error "must be valid ipv4 cidr"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, subnet, cidr

If I set up an AWS VPC with CIDR of 10.0.0.0/20 then the range is 10.0.0.0 to 10.0.15.255 
I make a subnet now. Why does 10.0.15.15/28 give an error. Isn't it's range 10.0.15.15 to 10.0.15.30 which is within the VPC?

Comment: Should probably be `10.0.15.240/28`.

Comment: No, 10.0.15.0 to 10.0.15.15 would be a /28 within that /20. I recommend using a subnet calculator: http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=10.0.0.0&mask1=20&mask2=28

Comment: Also as shown in the ipcalc results, subnetting a /20 into /28 would create 256 subnets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this site](https://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr) for some help.  `10.0.15.15/28` is `10.0.15.0` to `10.0.15.15`.  Perhaps you wanted `10.0.15.15/27` which goes to `10.0.15.31`.